# Refit an arima model with new training data in fable package

Tags: r, forecasting, arima, fable-r

I have a function which takes a fitted model and then refits that model to new training data (this is for step-ahead cross validation). For `lm` models it works like this:

```
#create data
training_data <-
    data.frame(date = seq.Date(
        from = as.Date("2020-01-01"),
        by = 1, length.out = 365
    ), x = 1:365, y = 1:365 + rnorm(n = 365))

# specify and fit model
lm_formula <- as.formula(y ~ x)
my_lm <- lm(lm_formula, data = training_data)

# refit on new training data
update(my_lm, data = new_training_data)
```

Is there a way to do the same thing for arima models fitted with the `fable` package? I'm creating the models like this

```
library(fable)
library(forecast)
arima_formula <- as.formula(y ~ x + PDQ(0, 0, 0))
my_arima <- as_tsibble(training_data) %>% model(ARIMA(arima_formula))
```

But I can't figure out a way to take the `my_arima` model that I've already fitted and pass it `new_training_data`, either using `update` or by extracting the formula and refitting as a new model. Note that although I've included the model formula in the reprex above, my function takes a fitted model rather than a formula. So just fitting a new model using `arima_formula` is not an option.

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the `refit()` function

Comment: Thanks for that and sorry I should have found on my own. If you want to post as an answer I can accept.